# Accessing user input from form always gives undefined values

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm making a web server to share information about me and increase my skill set. Please pardon my inexperience...

In my page there are 2 components: the first is a header area which displays my name and a tab menu which controls the content displayed in the second component. Thus, the header area is based on my index.js file and the content area is based on individual html files.

On one html file, the contact page, I have a contact form which is supposed to send emails to me. However, the form has input for text which only returns undefined values (unless they are hardcoded into the value property).

I've tried different ways to retrieve the user input; for instance, jquery and javascript. The values never change.

I've ensured unique IDs and names for tags and still no solution.

This is my index.js file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="/js/main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Kaushan+Script|Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
    <title> Blah Blaherson </title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <p class="banner">B. Blaherson</p>

    <div id="tab-anchor"></div>

    <ul class="tabs menu">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">About</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">CV</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Portfolio</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Contact</li>
    </ul> 


    <div class="main-content">
      <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current"></div>
      <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content"></div>
      <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content"></div>
      <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my tab-4.html which the contact html and contact form along with some inline javascript:

```
<div class="contact-content">
  <p class="form-title">Contact me by email</p>
  <div id="email" class="contact">

    <input type="hidden"></input>

      <div class="required">all fields are required</div>

      <div class="container">
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="hiddenName" id="hiddenNameId"></input>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="senderName" value="test"></input>
        <br>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <label for="email">Email Address: </label>
        <br>
        <input type="email" id="senderEmail"  maxlength="50"></input>
        <br>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <label for="subject">Subject: </label> 
        <br>
          <input type="text" id="subject" maxlength="50">HI</input>
        </br>
      </div>  

      <div class="container">
        <label for="message">Message: </label>
        <br>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="emailMessage"></textarea>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <input id="submit-button" onclick="sendEmail();" type='button' value="Submit"></input>
      </div>
</div>
<script>

  //email submit handler  

    function sendEmail() {

      //var name = document.getElementById("senderName").value; 
      //console.log(name); //does not print!

      function success(data) {
        if ( data.error ) {
          alert(data.error.message);
        } else {
          alert((JSON.parse(data.body)).message);
        }
      }

      function error(data) {
        alert(data);
      }

      var payload = {
        subject: $('#subject').val(),
        message: $('#emailMessage').val(), 
        name: $('#senderName').val(),
        email: $('#senderEmail').val()
      }
      console.log(payload);

      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/contact",
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: success,
        error: error,
        dataType: "application/json"
      });
    };
  </script>
</div>
```

Furthermore, I have a main.js file which controls the content display which can give a better idea of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//sticky navbar when scrolled down
  function navStick() {
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var divTop = $('#tab-anchor').offset().top;

      if (windowTop > divTop) {
        $('.menu').addClass('stick');
        $('#tab-anchor').height($('.menu').outerHeight());
      } else {
        $('.menu').removeClass('stick');
        $('#tab-anchor').height(0);
      }
  }
  $(function() {
    $(window).scroll(navStick);
    navStick();
  });

  $('.tab-content').load('/views/tab-1.html'); 

  $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').load('/views/'+tab_id+'.html');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');

  });

$(document).ready();
```

I should add that the AJAX call is working properly; although, the data consists of undefined values. I can get emails, but they are empty due to the undefined values.

Comment: Use jquery's event listener for the form's input. Monitor for say a keyup event (which is essentially any key being pressed when that form is selected) and then using jquery's .val() to get the value of the form. You are getting undefined because you are not "listening" for any changes to the form input.

Comment: @angkiki So I would have to take every key entered and concatenate it into a string. This seems so excessive. I ended up using bootstrap and it works now; however, I am still wondering why my initial approach did not work.

Comment: for future reference and sharing purposes i'll just let you know that my solution doesn't require any extra steps on your part. what happens is when the first key is pressed (say its "a"), `$('identifier').val()` will return "a". when the next key is pressed (say its "b"), now the `.val()` method will return "ab". so when the typing is finally done, you would simply get the full string value of whatever is in it.